# Fit collection view in keyboard extension swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, uicollectionview

I'm developing an emoji keyboard for iPhones and iPads. I'm using a collection view inside a .xib file which holds the collection view + a few buttons at the bottom. The xib is then used in a keyboardViewController.swift file like this:

```
let keyboard = UINib(nibName: "emojiKeyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first! as! UIView
keyboard.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
self.inputView.addSubview(keyboard)
```

I got everything working, the custom emojis show up in the collection view (They are another .xib file which holds a single cell that is repeated for each image).

My issue is that the view isn't resizing to fit within the bounds of the keyboard. The collection view overflows to fully fit all images meaning I can't see the buttons nor scroll/flip horizontal.

I've tried things like:

```
keyboard.sizeToFit()
keyboard.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

and the second line just somehow makes the entire view tiny (maybe 30x30px) in the top left corner of the keyboard.

Very grateful for any insights!

Comment: Please let me know if there's a need for more explanation of the setup :)